# Please correct my Code program C language

Tags: c

```
// Program jumlahBilangan.c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int jumlahDigit();

int jumlahDigit(int bilangan)
{
    if (bilangan == 0){
        return 0;
    }
        

    bilangan = 10;
}
        
    
int main()
{
    int bilangan, hasil;
    printf("Masukkan angka bilangan bulat: \n");
    scanf("%d", &bilangan);
    hasil = jumlahDigit(bilangan);
    printf("Jumlah digit angka bilangan: %d\n", hasil);
    return 0;
}
```

fix the program code, for example, enter the number 7631, then the function of the program will return the value 17 which is the sum of digits of the number.

The value 17 is the result of the addition (7+6+3+1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "so that it can output 7631 if I enter the value 17" Why is that the correct answer? It seems like you speak English well; it will be much easier for others to understand the problem if you use English-based variable names.

Comment: This `bilangan = 0` in `if` condition is assignment and not equality check.

Comment: Kindly include your code *Unbroken* by non-C-comment paragraphs. That will help with readability.

Comment: jumlahDigit is not used into the main, perhaps `hasil =  jumlahDigit(bilangan);` ?
Can you share your full code ? Use compiler warnings can help you too

Comment: As @H.S. said, you should write `if (bilingan == 0)`. Notice the two equal signs.

Comment: What do you want to happen if bilangan is not zero? You should program that, but did not. Because a) `bilangan = 10;` will never be executed. b) you do not have a `return` for that case. Also, I do not get the purpose of the whole `jumlahDigit()` function, because it is never called.

Comment: I've shared full codes :")

Comment: Very unlikely, why should your full code be without a call to the function?

Comment: If you would translate the identifiers in the code to English it would make it easier to guess things you are not explaining explicitly.

Comment: "with 10 is added to the evaluation result" I do not see 10 being added anywhere. A local variable (which is afterwards ignored - if not lucky) is set to 10 but nothing is added...

Comment: "output 7631 if I enter the value 17" How is that to happen? What is the logic? No adding of 10 will ever result in 7631 when starting at 17. If you want an output of 7631 for an input of 17 (or any other input) I recommend `printf("7631\n");`

Comment: You do not explain the desired logic of the code. The code is absolutely not doing what you describe it to do. It is not even using the function. You got a lot of help with obvious always-wrong details of your code, but the goal of the question cannot be achieved without much more explanation. I hence propose to close the question until more explanation is provided and a [mre] which at least loosely resembles the comments and the (then) given explanation in the question. Part of the MRE should be to activate warnings ( at least `-Wall`) and handle each warning or explain what blocks you.

Comment: thanks for all the explanations, I've finished my code. There is an error coming from me. I will close the question. Thank you very much senior brother

Comment: No. If you have a solution post it as an answer according to [answer]. Then edit the question to include all the info which was either asked for or which you needed to find your solution, i.e. according to [ask]. Then you get a good Q/A pair and I will happily upvote both. That will put your account into a position to efficiently get more help with future problems you encounter.

Comment: This site IMHO is not the place to ask for your homework to be solved.  This approach will make you the worst problem solver in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as asked cannot be answered, because there is insufficient explanation of how an input of 17 should arrive at an output of 7631.

However, in the spirit of [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) I will comment on the shown code, to enable the asker to improve to a point where the question can be focused on the correct algorithm.

```
// Program jumlahBilangan.c
#include <stdio.h>

int jumlahDigit(/* put at least int here, to match the function definition below */);

int jumlahDigit(int bilangan)
{
    if (bilangan = 0){ /* attention, =  is assignment, you most likely want == */
        return 0; /* at this point the function is left */
        bilangan = 10; /* this is never executed, even with == above) */
    }
    /* you probably want an else {...} here */
    /* with the "..." being something involving bilangan+=10; */
    /* in the end please make sure that you always end in a return statement */
}

int main(/* better add void here */)
{
    int bilangan, hasil; /* better initialise both variables here */
    printf("Masukkan angka bilangan bulat: \n");
    scanf("%d", &bilangan); /* consider not ignoring the return value here ... */
    hasil = bilangan; /* if scan fails, both are still not cleanly initialised, UB */

    /* somewhere here I expect a call to int jumlahDigit(int bilangan) */
    /* maybe replace above line by hasil = jumlahDigit(bilangan),
       but make sure to have return statements in all possible outcomes
       of that function */
    printf("Jumlah digit angka bilangan: %d\n", hasil);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry , i misread the question from the start, it should be that when I input for example the number 7631 then the question will produce a value of 17 . 17 is the result of the sum of the values ​​I input (7+6+3+1 = 17)

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question given by my teacher.
The error comes from me not concentrating, sorry

Comment: I see. Yes, mistaking the teachers question. That makes sense. My pleasure helping you to find that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int jumlahDigit();
int jumlahDigit(int bilangan){
if(bilangan==0) {
return 0; }
else
{
int hasil = 0;
while(bilangan != 0)
{
hasil = hasil + bilangan % 10;
bilangan = bilangan / 10;
}
return hasil;
}
}
int main()
{
int hasil, bilangan;
printf("Masukkan angka bilangan bulat: \n");
scanf("%d", &bilangan);
hasil = jumlahDigit(bilangan);
printf("Jumlah digit angka bilangan: %d\n", hasil);
return 0;
}
```

so, when I input for example the number 7631 then the question will produce a value of 17 . 17 is the result of the sum of the values ​​I input (7+6+3+1 = 17)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).